# ASP Wrong redirection after edit web.config

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, redirect

I try to edit the URL for homepage of an old ASP website. The file is `Default.aspx` and the current URL is `/homepage`.
I edit the web.config like this for use the new (test) URL `/homepage123`

```
<rule name="RedirectHomepage" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^Default\.aspx$" />
            <conditions>
              <add input="{REQUEST_METHOD}" pattern="^POST$" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="homepage123" appendQueryString="false" />
          </rule>
          <rule name="RewriteHomepage" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="homepage123" />
            <conditions>
              <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
              <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="Default.aspx" />
          </rule>
```

My problem is `/homepage123` don't work when I launch the app in visual studio.
When I try to reach `Default.aspx`, I am always redirected to `/homepage`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using IIS 7 or IIS 7.5 you can set the defaultDocument in webconfig file

```
<system.webServer>
  <defaultDocument>
    <files>
      <clear />
      <add value="homepage123.aspx" />
    </files>
  </defaultDocument>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Already set to Default.aspx. I use homepage for the exemple but the problem is the same for all urls